# Can't post data to the database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, database

Please help me, I cannot post my data to the database even though calling API
Here's my datacontext.js code:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const DataContext = createContext();

export const useData = () => {
    return useContext(DataContext);
};

export const DataProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({
        temperature: 0,
        humidity: 0,
        brightness: 0,
    });

    const updateData = async () => {
        const newTemperature = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        const newHumidity = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        const newBrightness = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

        setData({
            temperature: newTemperature,
            humidity: newHumidity,
            brightness: newBrightness,
        });

        // console.log("Data updated:", data);

        try {
            await axios.post('http://localhost:3002/api/addnewDataSensor', {
                temperature: newTemperature,
                humidity: newHumidity,
                brightness: newBrightness,
                createdAt: new Date().toString(),
            });
            console.log('Data sent to server successfully');
        } catch(error) {
            console.error('Error sending data to server:', error);
        }
    };

    const dataContextValue = { data, updateData };

    return (
        <DataContext.Provider value={dataContextValue}>
            {children}
        </DataContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

And here's my server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const port = 3002;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '123456',
    database: 'iot'
});

app.get('/api/getAllData', (req, res) => {
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM datasensors';

    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error executing query:', err);
            res.status(500).json({ err: 'Internal Server Error' });
        } else {
            // console.log('Data from database:', result);
            res.status(200).json(result);
        }
    });
});

app.post('/api/addnewDataSensor', (req, res) => {

    const { temperature, humidity, brightness, createdAt } = req.body;
    console.log('Received data:', { temperature, humidity, brightness, createdAt });
    
    if (!temperature || !humidity || !brightness || !createdAt) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Missing necessary information' });
    }

    const sql = 'INSERT INTO datasensors (temperature, humidity, brightness, createdAt) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)'
    const values = [temperature, humidity, brightness, createdAt];

    db.query(sql, values, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error executing query:', err);
            res.status(500).json({ err: 'Internal Server Error' });
        } else {
            console.log('The record has been added to the database');
            res.status(201).json({ message: 'The record has been added to the database' });
        }
    });
});

app.get('/api/getAllHistory', (req, res) => {
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM history';

    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error executing query:', err);
            res.status(500).json({ err: 'Internal Server Error' });
        } else {
            // console.log('Data from database:', result);
            res.status(200).json(result);
        }
    });
});


db.connect(err => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Lỗi kết nối tới cơ sở dữ liệu MySQL: " + err.stack);
        return;
    }
    console.log("Kết nối thành công đến cơ sở dữ liệu MySQL");
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server đang lắng nghe tại http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

I cannot call API '/api/addnewDataSensor' and I get this error on the console log
POST http://localhost:3002/api/addnewDataSensor 404 (Not Found)
DataContext.js:39 Error sending data to server: AxiosError {message: 'Request ...

Please help me, thank you very much